# NSMenu update title

Tags: objective-c, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have created an NSMenu that is dynamically created and lists the HDD's attached to the computer. Each of these is a submenu that contains a NSMenuItem that is created with the title "Calculating Size...". On another thread I am enumerating through some specific folders to return a string that will replace this title.

I have this all setup correctly but if I have one of these submenu's selected when the enumeration finishes it doesn't reflect the change in title until I either highlight the item or select a different submenu and come back.

What is the correct way of achieving this update?

Comment: It has a `view` property.  Why not try calling `-setNeedsDisplay:` on the thing?

Comment: @CodaFi I was unable to find anything relating to the ability to use -setNeedsDisplay with my NSMenu. I should clarify as well (not sure how I forgot to mention this is the first place). This is a NSMenu that is in a System Status Bar.

Comment: Don't call it directly on the menu!  `[self.menu.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];`